# Insert row with value depending on IF statement (in single query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's suppose we have table with images...

```
  image_id
  item_id
  main - flag-field, saying that image_id is main image for item with item_id
```

Is it possible to insert row into this table and determine `main` value on fly?
If there are no any images for `item_id` or there are no any images for `items_id` with `main`=1 - we should set `main`=1 for inserted row. Otherwise `main`=0;

Is it possible to make in a single SQL query?

Thank you.
PS: Sorry for my English. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. Not in one query.

You will need to count the rows first, in your php application, then set main depending on that.

You could do it in a trigger though if it was really important to do it in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, I suppose, I should use locking tables to prevent simulateous inserting two images with main=1 ? Is it possible with MyISAM tables?

Comment: You don't have to lock the whole table, you can use an advisory lock with just that item_id. Like this: `SELECT GET_LOCK('image_$item_id', 20)`. Read up on `GET_LOCK()` and `RELEASE_LOCK()`. Make sure to check the return value from `GET_LOCK()` to ensure it did not time out.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like that... now input values stored in variables, but it can be simple table...

```
create table #T (image_id int, item_id int, main int)
declare @new_image_id int, @new_item_id int

insert #T values (0,1,0)
insert #T values (0,1,0)
insert #T values (0,1,0)
insert #T values (0,2,0)
insert #T values (1,2,0)
insert #T values (1,2,0)

/*first example - no any images for item_id*/

select @new_image_id = 123, @new_item_id = 1

insert #T 
select @new_image_id, @new_item_id,
    CASE
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #T where item_id = @new_item_id and @new_image_id != 0)
            THEN 1
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #T where item_id = @new_item_id and main = 1)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END

/*second example - no any images for items_id with main=1*/

select @new_image_id = 234, @new_item_id = 2

insert #T 
select @new_image_id, @new_item_id,
    CASE
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #T where item_id = @new_item_id and @new_image_id != 0)
            THEN 1
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #T where item_id = @new_item_id and main = 1)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END

/*third example - new record with main = 0*/

select @new_image_id = 435, @new_item_id = 2

insert #T 
select @new_image_id, @new_item_id,
    CASE
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #T where item_id = @new_item_id and @new_image_id != 0)
            THEN 1
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #T where item_id = @new_item_id and main = 1)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END



select * from #T
```

Example on t-sql...

Max

Answer (score 0):

If your table looks somthing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    image_id SERIAL,
    item_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    main TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    path TINYTEXT NOT NULL
)
```

And you want to add the picture **'example.png'** to item **123**, you could use:

```
INSERT INTO images(item_id, main, path) 
SELECT new_image.item_id, IF(images.item_id IS NULL, 1, 0), new_image.path 
FROM (SELECT 123 as item_id, 'example.png' as path) AS new_image
LEFT JOIN images USING (item_id)
LIMIT 1;
```